# ¿Como sacar la data por semana ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy implementando una consulta en donde pueda obtener la data de cada semana por ejemplo estoy con la semana **01** que seria entre **31/12/2018** **al** **06/01/2019**

**Consulta pasandole la fecha manualmente:**

```
SELECT FECHA_MUESTRA DIA,
             LABEL,
             DL_OUT_TH_KBPS,
             ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2)
                TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
        FROM V_GF_DATA_GW_TH_KBPS
       WHERE FECHA_MUESTRA >=
                TO_DATE ('31/12/2018 00:00:00', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
             AND FECHA_MUESTRA <=
                    TO_DATE ('06/01/2019 23:59:59',
                             'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS')
    ORDER BY FECHA_MUESTRA DESC, label DESC
```

Esta me funciona bien me trae todos los registros serian **2016**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Consulta extrayendo automaticamente:**

```
SELECT FECHA_MUESTRA DIA,
             LABEL,
             DL_OUT_TH_KBPS,
             ROUND ( (DL_OUT_TH_KBPS + UL_INC_TH_KBPS) / (1000 * 1000), 2)
                TOTAL_DL_UL_GBPS
        FROM V_GF_DATA_GW_TH_KBPS
       WHERE 
    FECHA_MUESTRA >= trunc(sysdate,'iw')-7
    AND FECHA_MUESTRA <= trunc(sysdate,'iw')-1
    ORDER BY FECHA_MUESTRA DESC, label DESC
```

Esta consulta solo me trae un total **1729**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que veo no me esta trayendo los del utlimo dia **"06/01/2019"**

Comment: si en ves de "and" pruebas con "between"?, para el rango de fechas o tambien prodrías hacer esto trunc(FECHA_MUESTRA,'iw') >=.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la consulta manual has escrito esta hora "23:59:59" y  `trunc(sysdate,'iw')-1` te trae esta otra "00:00:00". Para evitar esto cambia la comparación asi: 
`AND FECHA_MUESTRA < trunc(sysdate,'iw')`

Comment: Gracias me sirvio..